# Can I send email via pure javascript

Tags: mailgun

I'm using mailgun as my mail service,

I wonder how to using mailgun to send email via pure javascript in a static website, no backend program

Answer (score 0):

Mailgun does not support a plain JavaScript (with no Backend) interaction. You cannot make AJAX request to Mailgun.
This is actually a good thing for security/safety of your application. Also Mailgun requires server-side authentication (over HTTPS) for all your endpoints, so think about using cURL, nodejs, ruby, python or Java as a way better option to interact with Mailgun

Happy emailing!